# How to change angular model value from other controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

here is the small angular code.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="personCtrl">
    <button ng-click="toggle()">Hide user</button>
    <p ng-hide="myVar">
    First Name: <input type=text ng-model="firstName"><br>
    Last Name: <input type=text ng-model="lastName"><br><br>
    Full Name: {{firstName + " " + lastName}}
    </p>

    </div>

    <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('personCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.firstName = "John",
        $scope.lastName = "Doe"
        $scope.myVar = false;
        $scope.toggle = function() {
            $scope.myVar = !$scope.myVar;
        }
    });
    </script> 
    </body>
```

so when we are changing value in textboxes then change is reflected in label. suppose i have a other button called Test. i want when user will click on test button then by ng js code i will change value in first name textbox by other ng controller code. if possible please help me with code. thanks

Comment: you could use $broadcast to communicate between controller

Comment: can u plzz come with small sample code because just learning angular. thanks

Comment: Can you provide a more complete example that shows what you are trying to do and has the other controller defined? I'm interested in why you would need more than one controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
<body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="testCtrl">
        <input type="text" ng-model="name"> 
        <button ng-click="send()" >Send</button>
    </div>

    <div ng-controller="testCtrl2">
        <input type="text" ng-model="name"> 
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>   
</body>
</html>
```

--- app.js ------------------

```
var app= angular.module('app',[]);

app.controller('testCtrl',function($scope,$rootScope){
    $scope.name = "test";
    $scope.send = function(){
    $rootScope.$broadcast('sendEvent', { any: $scope.name });
});

app.controller('testCtrl2',function($scope, $rootScope){
    $rootScope.$on('sendEvent', function(event, args) {
    $scope.name = args.any;
});
```

Comment: Good point, changed the answer, so this is just basic solution, bootstrapping could be done more nicely

Comment: i am just learning angular. so would you mind to explain how your program will work ? just need to understand the flow.

Comment: so in index.html we have two areas, both with their own controller, by pressing send button in the first area we trigger ng-click and send() method. This triggers a broadcast which sends the data to anyone who listens. In this case testCtrl2 listens which you can see on $rootScope.$on('sendEvent',function(event,args){});

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to offer another approach.

**DO** Use Factories to manipulate models.

**DON'T** use broadcasts beause your app on a larger scle will have appwide braodcast shooting all over the place for no reason.

If you build your application this way, you'll have a much easier time manipulating models and making sure they're synced across the application. it'll eventually make testing and stack tracing easier when you get to that in the future.

Note: I exposed a method to update the model on click,but it doesn't really matter, I mainly did it to show you how to manipulate all your model changes in the factory and simply use very small controllers to trigger then changes if you need to.

Example HTML:

```
<html>
<body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="testCtrl as test">
        <input type="text" ng-model="test.model.name"> 
    </div>

    <div ng-controller="testCtrl2 as test2">
        <input type="text" ng-model="test2.model.name"> 
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>   
</body>
</html>
```

Example app.js

```
(function(){
    "use strict";

    angular.module('app',[]);

    function testCtrl( testFactory ){
        var testCtrl = this;

        testCtrl.model = testFactory.model;
        testCtrl.send = testFactory.updateName;
    }

    function testCtrl2( testFactory ){
        var testCtrl2 = this;

        testCtrl2.model = testFactory.model;
    }

    function testFactory(){
        var testFactory = this;

        testFactory.model = {
            name: "test"
        };

        testFactory.updateName = function( newValue ){
            testFactory.model.name = newValue;
        }

        return testFactory;
    }

    angular.module('app')
        .controller('testCtrl', ['testFactory', testCtrl])
        .controller('testCtrl2', ['testFactory', testCtrl2])
        .factory('testFactory', [testFactory]);


})();
```

If you want a nice best practices tutorial look at this to start: http://toddmotto.com/opinionated-angular-js-styleguide-for-teams/

Comment: what is the meaning of this line of code `angular.module('app')
        .controller('testCtrl', ['testFactory', testCtrl])
        .controller('testCtrl2', ['testFactory', testCtrl2])
        .factory('testFactory', [testFactory]);
`

Comment: That's where you bind your two controllers and factory to your application, read the article, it explain this all in detail and it's a much better format than a so comment, this is the first and second point.